How to properly deal damage?
I'm trying to deal damage to my player when the enemy is at a given distance, but whatever I try the player’s life goes instantly to 0. I tried to add the StartCoroutine(ReduceHealthOverTime()); line in the player script and the slider and health are perfectly decreasing. I also tried different approaches, but the result is always the same.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float maxHealth = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float currentHealth = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private Slider healthSlider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Initialize health
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

        // Configure the slider
        if (healthSlider != null)
        {
            healthSlider.minValue = 0f;
            healthSlider.maxValue = 1f;
            UpdateHealthUI();
        }

        // Start the coroutine to remove 1 health every second
        //StartCoroutine(ReduceHealthOverTime());
    }

    public void SetHealth(float health)
    {
        currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(health, 0f, maxHealth);
        UpdateHealthUI();
    }

    public void TakeDamage(float damage)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Before damage: Health = {currentHealth}, Damage = {damage}");
        currentHealth = Mathf.Max(0f, currentHealth - damage);
        Debug.Log($"After damage: Health = {currentHealth}");
        UpdateHealthUI();
    }

    public void Heal(float amount)
    {
        currentHealth = Mathf.Min(maxHealth, currentHealth + amount);
        UpdateHealthUI();
    }

    private void UpdateHealthUI()
    {
        if (healthSlider != null)
        {
            // Convert current health to 0-1 range for the slider
            healthSlider.value = currentHealth / maxHealth;
        }

        // Log the current health to see if slider is working
        Debug.Log("Current Health: " + currentHealth + " (Slider Value: " + (healthSlider != null ? healthSlider.value.ToString() : "No Slider") + ")");
    }

    // Coroutine to reduce health by 1 every second
    private IEnumerator ReduceHealthOverTime()
    {
        while (currentHealth > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            TakeDamage(1f);
        }
    }

    // Getters for current and max health
    public float GetCurrentHealth() => currentHealth;
    public float GetMaxHealth() => maxHealth;
}

using UnityEngine;
using Assets.FantasyMonsters.Common.Scripts;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float baseStopDistance = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float stopDistanceVariation = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField] private bool faceMovementDirection = true;
    
    [Header("Attack Settings")]
    [SerializeField] private float attackCooldown = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float normalAttackDamage = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float altAttackDamage = 20f;
    
    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    [SerializeField] private bool debugMode = true;

    private float actualStopDistance;
    private Monster monsterScript;
    private Animator animator;
    private PlayerHealth playerHealth;
    private bool canAttack = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Initialize stop distance with random variation
        actualStopDistance = baseStopDistance + Random.Range(-stopDistanceVariation, stopDistanceVariation);
        
        // Get required components
        monsterScript = GetComponent<Monster>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
        // Set up player reference and health component
        if (player != null)
        {
            playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
            if (playerHealth == null && debugMode)
            {
                Debug.LogError("PlayerHealth component not found on player!");
            }
        }

        // Check for required components
        if (monsterScript == null && debugMode)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Monster component not found on enemy!");
        }
        if (animator == null && debugMode)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Animator component not found on enemy!");
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (player == null) return;

        float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (distanceToPlayer > actualStopDistance)
        {
            // Move towards player
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            
            // Handle rotation
            if (faceMovementDirection)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -90, 0);
            }
            
            // Update animation state
            monsterScript?.SetState(MonsterState.Walk);

            // Reset attack animation
            if (animator != null)
            {
                animator.ResetTrigger("Attack");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // When in range, stop and attack
            monsterScript?.SetState(MonsterState.Idle);
            
            // Only try to attack if we can
            if (canAttack && playerHealth != null)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Attack());
            }
        }

        if (debugMode)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + Vector3.left * actualStopDistance, Color.red);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Attack()
    {
        if (!canAttack) yield break;
        
        canAttack = false;
        
        if (debugMode)
        {
            Debug.Log($"[{gameObject.name}] Starting attack");
        }

        // Play attack animation
        if (animator != null)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
        }

        // Deal damage
        if (playerHealth != null)
        {
            if (debugMode)
            {
                Debug.Log($"[{gameObject.name}] Dealing {normalAttackDamage} damage");
            }
            playerHealth.TakeDamage(normalAttackDamage);
        }

        // Wait for cooldown
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackCooldown);
        
        canAttack = true;
    }

    public void SetPlayer(Transform playerTransform)
    {
        player = playerTransform;
        if (player != null)
        {
            playerHealth = player.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Make sure we can attack when re-enabled
        canAttack = true;
    }
}


when i call takeDamage from the debug coro it convertsto 0.99 0.98...

I can't find anything wrong from just the code itself. Do some debugging steps- does "Starting attack" and "Dealing {normalAttackDamage} damage" only print once per attack? Does the "Before damage" and "After damage" make sense?

so i found something. i recreated everything from scratch. the first time i run the code it works.
then if i stop the player and press play again, currentHealth is set to 0
so maybe a problem in currentHealth = maxHealth; this line of awake? sorry but im new to unity
i tried to remove [SerializeField]  from currenthealth but it always starts at 0

Is something calling SetHealth?

after playing around with it for some time, liiks like  [SerializeField] private float currentHealth = 100f; is retained everytime i start the game. so i removed serialize field but it still happening, maybe im changing the value to the prefab itself instead of the in game one?

do you have some form of "remember values" going on?

Damage is something you calculate and apply during each frame update; based on distance, firing "time" (per frame), men left standing, etc. Losses are applied and the cycle repeats until one party withdraws, charges, and / or is destroyed.
